# How to initialise std shared pointer for valarray

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

I am trying to initialise a shared pointer of `std::valarray<double>`, my code is

```
class foo {

    public:

        foo();

    private:

        std::shared_ptr<std::valarray<double>> meanValues;
};
```

In the constructor, I would like to fill up `meanValues`

```
foo::foo() {

    this->meanValues = std::make_shared<std::valarray<double>>(2);
}
```

How do I fill up `meanValues` to have two values `{1.2, 4.5}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can explicitly specify the `std::initializer_list`:

```
foo::foo()
{
    this->meanValues = std::make_shared<std::valarray<double>>(std::initializer_list<double>{1.2, 4.5});
}
```